# Como debug erros no Realm DB?

Tags: swift, thread, multithreading, commit, realmdb

Como posso debugar este erro e saber a origem dele:

lib

> c++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm ::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geralmente este erro ocorre por que vc declara o seu realm fora de um thread e está usando alguma propriedade dele dentro de uma thread.
Exemplo

```
let realm = try! Realm()
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { 
                //não pode utilizar o realm declarado fora da GDC detro da GDC pois da erro de thread incorret
                let pessoa = realm.objects(Pessoa).first

            })
```

Comment: Vlw!!! Eu consegui resolver mas esqueci de colocar aqui!!

Answer (score 1):

Eu nunca mexi com RealmDB, mas, pela mensagem de erro, parece que você está tentando acessar o Realm por uma thread não autorizada.

Dei uma procurada na Internet e achei isso daqui:

> ### Multi-threading com Realm
>
> A única regra à respeito do uso de Realm através de threads é que instâncias do Realm, RealmObject ou RealmResult não podem ser passadas de uma thread para outra. Quando você quer acessar o mesmo dado a partir de threads diferentes, você deve obter uma instância separada para cada thread (através de Realm.getInstance(this), por exemplo) e acessar seus objetos através de uma RealmQuery. Apesar dos objetos serem diferentes, eles se referem ao mesmo dado no disco e será possível ler e escrever neles a partir de qualquer thread!

Acredito que você tem uma instância do Realm criada em alguma thread (na principal, por exemplo) e está tentando acessar o objeto por outra thread.

Sugestão de debug:

1. Coloca dois breakpoints no código:

   1. Na linha onde você cria o objeto [1]
   2. Na linha do erro, onde você acessa o objeto [2]
2. Executa o projeto
3. Quando o debugger interceptar o código no breakpoint [1], checa no Debug Navigator (atalho: Command + 6) qual a thread onde o objeto está sendo criado
4. Deixa o código continuar e tenta reproduzir o erro
5. Quando o debugger interceptar o código no breakpoint [2], faz a mesma coisa da primeira vez: olha o Debug Navigator e verifica em qual thread aquele código está sendo executado

Talvez você consiga encontrar o problema por aí!